# How to add a button to a column in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, datarow

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Software Title", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Version", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Uninstall", typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Button)));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[0] = "App";
dr[1] = "1.0";
Button uninstall = new Button();
uninstall.Text = "Uninstall";

dr[2] = uninstall;

dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dataGridViewSoftware.DataSource = dt;
```

The text appears but button never shows up.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting, You don't have to add the button in your DataTable, instead you have to add a column to your gridview with button.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? Winform, WPF , ASP.Net ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Assuming you are in Windows Forms, you need to add a `DataGridViewButtonColumn` to your `DataGridView` - Not directly to the `DataTable`.

This should occur somewhere after you bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGridView`.

Something like this should work:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn uninstallButtonColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
uninstallButtonColumn.Name = "uninstall_column";
uninstallButtonColumn.Text = "Uninstall";
int columnIndex = 2;
if (dataGridViewSoftware.Columns["uninstall_column"] == null)
{
    dataGridViewSoftware.Columns.Insert(columnIndex, uninstallButtonColumn);
}
```

Of course you will have to handle the `CellClick` event of the grid to do anything with the button.

Add this somewhere in your DataGridView Initialization code

```
dataGridViewSoftware.CellClick += dataGridViewSoftware_CellClick;
```

Then create the handler:

```
private void dataGridViewSoftware_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridViewSoftware.Columns["uninstall_column"].Index)
    {
        //Do something with your button.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a button column?

Comment: nevermind. I see you meant to say uninstallButtonColumn instead of buttonColumn. How do you attack the cellclick event?

Comment: Edited my answer to address this... you should probably read up on event handling.

Comment: Should edit the answer to include the `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` or else the button will not have any text inside.

Comment: In the above example there is an important line is missing 
Please add "  uninstallButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;"

Answer (score 17):

Make it simple.

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
{
    button.Name = "button";
    button.HeaderText = "Button";
    button.Text = "Button";
    button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; //dont forget this line
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
}
```

Comment: Without `UseColumnTextForButtonValue` the button in each row does not have any content!

Comment: @user3454439 yeah dont forget that one line

Answer (score 2):

You can use the best method using below

```
                gvEmployees.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                gvEmployees.ColumnCount = 4;


                DataGridViewButtonColumn SelectButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                SelectButton.Name = "Select";
                SelectButton.Text = "Select";
                SelectButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                if (gvEmployees.Columns["Select"] == null)
                {
                    gvEmployees.Columns.Insert(0, SelectButton);
                }

                DataGridViewButtonColumn DeleteButton = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
                DeleteButton.Name = "Delete";
                DeleteButton.Text = "Delete";
                DeleteButton.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
                if (gvEmployees.Columns["Delete"] == null)
                {
                    gvEmployees.Columns.Insert(1, DeleteButton);
                }

                gvEmployees.Columns[2].Name = "EmployeeID";
                gvEmployees.Columns[2].HeaderText = "EmployeeID";
                gvEmployees.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "EmployeeID";
```