# Datagridview Button Programming

Tags: c#

i am programming a piece of software for a loyalty scheme. I have basically finished all of it. The only thing i am stuck on for ages is programming the buttons for the datagridview which i am using for my redeem offers page. I have gotten it to add a button to the end of each row automatically when you add a new offer but i am clueless on how to program it to recognize each row.

for e.g.)
Row1) Offer 1 is X name and costs Y 
Row2) offer 2 is Z Name and costs F

I can only seem to find the ability to program every single button at once and not individual and even so, i need it to work automatically so when i can add a offer i can immediately purchase it. How would i get it to recognize which row i am on?
here is what my form and database looks like.
[Picture Of Form - (picture link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhuKt.png)

[What my database looks like - (picture link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSdWx.png)

Comment: [How to add a button to a column in the DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191950/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-column-in-the-datagridview)

Comment: Any code to show? [ask]

Answer (score 2):

below ur class

make public int id;

//adding button

```
 DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
    col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True;
    col.Text = "ADD";
    col.Name = "Btn_add";
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

//pass id values here to do functions..

```
private void Btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

   }
```

//this gets selected index of selected row value

private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
     int id =  DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value;
```

}

Comment: Hey, what would i call the value for                                                       
yourdatagridname int id =  yourdatagridname.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value;              my datagrid is called DataGridView1 but its not recognized

Comment: I did, but now i am receiving an error to say  i cant use 'SelectedRows' as a method anymore. i right clicked my datagrid view and copied the name 'offersDataGridView' to it and it is recognizing it now but it says i cant use selectedrows.

Comment: Please give me 15 minutes, i am on a break now. I will be back at the computer then. Please check back in 15 mins i appreciate it

Comment: where does the code for add button go? on form load?

Comment: I have gotten it to almost work. Now it just says the 'Cells' part is a error with no possible fixes given.

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: the btn_add_click function, what would i put in that? do i put the code i want the button to do in it?

Comment: yes put the functionality there.. and please upvote my answer

Comment: Where does the add button code go? do i make it a private void? or do i just put it under the namespace thing

Comment: make the button clicking event  like other.. do the functionality there as u want..

Comment: im still having alot of issues. I need to get it so when i click on the button in the column it can show the data in a messagebox of whats in the row? i can give you the positive reputation if u can solve it, its what im struggling with i need to get it so when i click the button the messagebox appears with the data in the row

Answer (score 0):

In Datagrid please bind OfferId in buy button. When press button then automatically gives id onclick event.

Comment: fam, how i cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hook into the [RowDataBound Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.7.2). This event is called, each time a new entry is put into the table. At this point, you can add a button to the tabe and add a custom action/url to the url.