# Winform Datagridview button column button with multiline text

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I've created a button column successfully based on the following post, including adding text to the individual buttons:

[How to add a button to a column in the DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191950/how-to-add-a-button-to-a-column-in-the-datagridview)

The problem is, my text won't fit on a single line, so I'm hoping to create a multiline button label.

Here is the code I'm using to define the column, but the Environment.Newline doesn't seem to work on these buttons. Is there a way to create multiline button label for datagridview buttons and, if so, how?

```
        Dim inspectionNotesButtonCol As New DataGridViewButtonColumn With {
            .Name = "InspNotesButton",
            .HeaderText = "Insp." + Environment.NewLine + "Notes",
            .Text = "Insp." + Environment.NewLine + "Notes",
            .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True,
            .Width = 50
        }
        Me.dgvIssues.Columns.Add(inspectionNotesButtonCol)
```

Answers in either C# or vb.net are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the grids `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` and `AutoSizeRowsMode` should allow you to display multiple lines in the button cells. Something like…

```
Dim inspectionNotesButtonCol As New DataGridViewButtonColumn With {
        .Name = "InspNotesButton",
        .HeaderText = "Insp." + Environment.NewLine + "Notes",
        .Text = "Insp." + Environment.NewLine + "Notes",
        .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True,
        .Width = 50
    }
dgvIssues.Columns.Add(inspectionNotesButtonCol)
dgvIssues.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
dgvIssues.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
dgvIssues.Rows.Add()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `MultiLine` property to `True` and then try to use `Environment.NewLine`. There are several controls sharing the behavior you have experienced, `TextBox` is another example.

Comment: There is no Multiline option for DatagridViewButtonCell or DataGridViewButtonColumn. What object would I set Multiline to?

Comment: @EdwardBagby you are right and I was wrong. So, let's try with \n instead of Environment.NewLine. If it works, I will edit my answer. If not, I will remove it.